# Manually deallocating NSValue

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, nsautoreleasepool

Is it possible to instantiate a NSValue with a pointer to a C structure without having to create a autorelease pool? For the moment, I do this:

```
NSValue* val = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(const void*)structure];
```

but this is release by the autorelease pool. I would like to take control of this and be able to dealloc it when I want. Is this possible? I tried this:

```
NSValue* value = [[NSValue alloc] initWithBytes:(const void*)structure objCType:@encode(const void*)];
[value release];
```

but it is crashing for some reason. Any other way to be able to release immediately?
Thanks!

Comment: any error log available?

Comment: Note that if you are trying to avoid the autorelease pool while writing Foundation code, it is pretty much futile.  Don't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to be passing a *pointer to the type* that's given for the `objCType:` argument. You're passing a variable *of the type*. So, for example, if you have a variable `int foo` that you want to store in an NSValue, you'd write `[[NSValue alloc] initWithBytes:&foo objCType:@encode(int)]`. So if you want to store a pointer, you need to pass a pointer to that pointer as the bytes. Passing the pointer itself will cause NSValue to try to follow the pointer and then treat the bytes that it's pointing to as a pointer as well.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSValue* val = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(const void*)structure];
[val retain];
```